# Is it wrong to share a video displaying something embarrassing of people I don't know on Facebook?

Tags: halal-haram, social-media

I recently saw a video on Facebook, which showed some people trying to figure out how long it takes someone to go 80 miles if they're going 80 mph. I shared it, but I shared it to make a sarcastic point about if this will be blamed on our education system.

Now this made me think about how Muslims aren't supposed to publicize their own sins, or other sins, or humiliate other people publicly, or even in front of them I guess. The individuals in the video aren't named or anything, and it's a popular video that lot of people saw.

Is it wrong to share a video displaying something embarrassing of people I don't know on Facebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure we will be asked for what we did in this world. But it has levels and situations:

1. if that persons in that video be okay with the sharing in first place you didn't anything wrong.
2. if you be the first person upload and shared that video without permission you did wrong and will be asked most (solution: find them recover their damage made by you and ask them to forgive you)
3. if you just shared from anywhere else and that person won't be okay in first place you will be asked but less than person mention in the second point